# Make FormidablePro Calendar View Responsive

Tags: php, calendarview, formidable

I have set up an event calendar for an organization using Formidable Pro. I need the ability to use the recurring event option, however the only display supported with this option is the Calendar View and the Calendar view displays as [very skinny columns on smart devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0LkG.png) — not good.

I added some css and edited the code in the calendar.php file to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0LkG.png#1):

My css:

```
    @media 
only screen and (max-width: 1920px)
 /*(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)*/ {


  .frmcal table.frmcal-calendar tbody tr td {
    display:inline; 
    width:100%;
   }

   table.frmcal-calendar .frmcal_date {
     padding: 6px 5px;
     background-color: #dedad1;
   }

   table.frmcal-calendar .frmcal-today .frmcal_date  {
     padding: 6px 5px;
     background-color: #dedad1;
     text-align:center;
   }

   table.frmcal-calendar .frmcal_date {
     text-align:center;
   }

   .frmcal-content {
     padding:14px 12px;
   }
}
```

The code before my changes:

```
<div class="frmcal_num"><?php echo $day ?></div></div> <div class="frmcal-content">
```

The code after my changes:

```
<div class="frmcal_num"><?php echo $day_names[$i], $month, ' / ', $day, ' / ', $year ?></div></div> <div class="frmcal-content”>
```

I would like to remove the rows of day names (Sun, Mon, Tues,…) you see in the first image link and add them to the start of the date. I would like to convert the month number to the month name so it would display like: Monday, August 3, 2015.

Help?

Full code of the calendar.php file.

```
    <?php

for ( $i = $week_begins; $i < ( $maxday+$startday ); $i++ ) {
    $pos = $i % 7;
    $end_tr = false;
    if ( $pos == $week_begins ) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
    }

    $day = $i - $startday + 1;

    //add classes for the day
    $day_class = '';

    //check for today
    if ( isset( $today ) && $day == $today ) {
        $day_class .= ' frmcal-today';
    }

    if ( $pos == $week_begins || $pos == $week_ends ) {
        $day_class .= ' frmcal-week-end';
    }

?>
<td<?php echo ( ! empty( $day_class ) ) ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $day_class ) . '"' : ''; ?>><div class="frmcal_date"><?php
echo isset($day_names[$i]) ? $day_names[$i] .' ' : '';
unset($day_class);

    if ( $i >= $startday ) {
        ?><div class="frmcal_num"><?php echo $day ?></div></div> <div class="frmcal-content">
<?php
        if ( isset($daily_entries[$i]) && ! empty($daily_entries[$i]) ) {
            foreach ( $daily_entries[$i] as $entry ) {
                //Set up current entry date for [event_date] shortcode
                $current_entry_date = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . ( $day < 10 ? '0' . $day : $day );

                if ( isset($used_entries[$entry->id]) ) {
                    $this_content = FrmProFieldsHelper::replace_calendar_date_shortcode($used_entries[$entry->id], $current_entry_date);
                    echo '<div class="frm_cal_multi_'. $entry->id .'">'. $this_content .'</div>';
                } else {
                    // switch [event_date] to [calendar_date] so it can be replaced on each individual date instead of each entry
                    $new_content = str_replace( array( '[calendar_date]', '[calendar_date '), array( '[calendar_date]', '[calendar_date '), $new_content);
                    $this_content = apply_filters('frm_display_entry_content', $new_content, $entry, $shortcodes, $display, $show, '', array( 'calendar_date' => $current_entry_date));

                    $used_entries[$entry->id] = $this_content;
                    $this_content = FrmProFieldsHelper::replace_calendar_date_shortcode($this_content, $current_entry_date);
                    echo $this_content;

                    unset($this_content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?></div>
</td>
<?php
    if ( $pos == $week_ends ) {
        $end_tr = true;
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}

$pos++;
if ( $pos == 7 ) {
    $pos = 0;
}
if ( $pos != $week_begins ) {
    if ( $pos > $week_begins ) {
        $week_begins = $week_begins+7;
    }
    for ( $e=$pos; $e<$week_begins; $e++ ) {
        echo "<td></td>\n";
    }
}

if ( ! $end_tr ) {
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: You might want to include more of the code used to render the calendar so that a non FormidablePro user can review a bit more of the code. You could be helped by a php developer for example

Comment: @Kerridge0 Sorry. I added it to the original post.